# Twilio Salesforce integration (Chat Transcripts)

Tags: salesforce, twilio, twilio-flex

I am currently working on a Twilio POC Project using the Twilio Flex integration with Salesforce. I have already connected to WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, SMS, and Web Chat. All interactions are tracked on Salesforce tasks.[Task view on Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTRaq.png)

I would also like to have the chat transcript as well on Salesforce, in addition to the basic info that Twilio puts on tasks. Does anybody have any experience or advice related to this? Thanks